# Grails GSP button conditioning

Tags: grails, gsp

How to disable or just hide button conditionaly depending of some controller logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the <if> tags,

```
<g:if test="${showButton}">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</g:if>
```

Comment: That's the Boolean expression. showButton is simply a variable defined elsewhere